# VueJS v-for in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How can I create a list in laravel (v7) blade using the VueJS *v-for* method?

**inside home.blade.php:**

```
<template v-for="(item,index) in this.list">
    <qm-item number="@{{index}}"></qm-item>
</template>
```

in the source code this results in:

```
<qm-item number="index"></qm-item>
```

but i would like to have number=0 or =1 on the first *qm-item*, number=2 on the second and so on.

**UPDATE:** the issue was how I was checking it, since the DOM is re-rendered I cannot check in the browser source code for this, because this won't be up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `bind` the number as follows:

```
<qm-item :number="index"></qm-item>
```

Comment: hm, in the source code with this I get: :number="index"

Comment: What is the package name of qm-item?

Comment: Ah, sorry you were right, I checked the wrong way. Since this stuff is rendered dynamically I can't check in the brwoser source code, since that's not up to date then. So your solution works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `number`:

```
<template v-for="(item,index) in this.list">
    <qm-item :number="index"></qm-item>
</template>
```

`index` will be defined on the Vue.js side, not on the Laravel side.

Comment: Ah, sorry you were right, I checked the wrong way. Since this stuff is rendered dynamically I can't check in the brwoser source code, since that's not up to date then. So your solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass data from blade to your Vue component you have to bind the props with a leading `:`
So, in your case, it should be `<qm-item :number="{{index}}"></qm-item>`
Also, use variable just like you normally do in the blade.